# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, fetch

I am working in a currency converting react-app and i am having a problem:
I am trying to fetch currencies from latest api like this:

```
callAPI(base) {
        const api = `https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=${base}`;
        fetch(api)
            .then(results => {
                return results.json();
            }).then(data => this.setState({
            rates: data['rates'],
            currencies: Object.keys(data['rates']).sort()
        }));
    }
```

My constructor is declared like below:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [{
                baseCurrency: 'GBP',
                baseAmount: 0,
                convertToCurrency: 'USD',
                rates: [],
                currencies: []
            },
                ]
        }
        this.callAPI = this.callAPI.bind(this);
    }
```

When i change my constructor in this way i can fetch currencies and select them:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
                baseCurrency: 'GBP',
                baseAmount: 0,
                convertToCurrency: 'USD',
                rates: [],
                currencies: []
            }
        }
        this.callAPI = this.callAPI.bind(this);
    }
```

Can you suggest me something, why when i declare the values inside an array it doesn't work?
The error does show in this line:

```
currencies: Object.keys(data['rates']).sort()
```

I have these other functions too:

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.callAPI(this.state.baseCurrency)
    }
    changeBaseCurrency(e) {
        this.setState({ baseCurrency: e.target.value});
        this.callAPI(e.target.value)
    }
 getConvertedCurrency(baseAmount,convertToCurrency,rates) {
        return Number.parseFloat(baseAmount * rates[convertToCurrency]).toFixed(2);
    }
```

Inside the render function i have these:

```
const [{currencies,rates,baseCurrency,baseAmount,convertToCurrency}] = this.state.data;
        const result = this.getConvertedCurrency(baseAmount, convertToCurrency, rates);
        const currencyChoice = currencies.map(currency =>
            <option key={currency} value={currency}> {currency} </option>
        );
```

Inside the return function i have these:

```
<select
                            value={baseCurrency}
                            className='form-control'
                            id = 'base-currency'
                            onChange={this.changeBaseCurrency}
                            ref = {input => this.baseCurrency = input}
                        >
                            {currencyChoice}
                            <option>{baseCurrency}</option>
                        </select>
```

Comment: If the error points to `Object.keys(data['rates']).sort()` that means `data["rates"]` is `undefined`. Are you use `data.rates` exists after you make the `API` call?

Comment: I have edited my previous post with the rest of functions, if you can suggest me something? Thank you!

Comment: The code you're showing is irrelevant - make sure that `data.rates` has a value after you make the `API` call. The error is suggesting that it doesn't.

Comment: The code is working if i am using i am using the second constructor which i have mentioned it in the question too